# Wifi crashes when uploading large file (>1GB)

Tags: networking, wireless, upload

When I try to upload a large file (>1GB) from my ubuntu desktop either to google drive or s3 bucket my wifi crashes (it uploads a bit and then acts as if there is no internet available). The only to restore functionality is to turn of wifi in settings and then turn it back on. Downloading large files or watching movies/etc does not have this effect. Other devices (iOS/OSX/windows) are able to use the same wifi connection without these issues and are able to upload large files without the network problem. Also, this desktop dual boots into win10 and when running win10 it can upload large files without problem.

Ubuntu version:

```
> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Some network info:

```
> sudo lshw -class network -short && nmcli device status 

H/W path                Device          Class          Description
==================================================================
/0/100/1.2/0/3/0        wlp5s0          network        Wi-Fi 6 AX200
/0/100/1.2/0/4/0        enp6s0          network        I211 Gigabit Network Conn
DEVICE          TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlp5s0          wifi      connected     BiteBiteFi 
docker0         bridge    connected     docker0    
p2p-dev-wlp5s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected  --         
enp6s0          ethernet  unavailable   --         
lo              loopback  unmanaged     --
```

How do I go about resolving this?

Thanks!